Youtube API and Oauth client seem to not working properly
The Oauth client seem be the same for both projects but they act differently when calling the API.
I tried uplaoding videos using the API. It seems to be working but then some of them ran by the exact same code only on a different project and using a different OAuth 2.0 Client IDs don't end up working as public and get locked up by youtube. (they get uploaded as private(locked)). I think I am setting up the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs the exact same way but don't know why some work and some don't. Has anyone got a suggestion by any chance?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
